# Maintaining records of iOS in-app-purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've implemented IAPs where there's a one time purchase that unlocks some feature in the app. Since the purchase is made only once by each user I can just ask Apple's IAP service if this user has the made the purchase. If so then unlock the feature. If not then display the IAP prompt. I probably also persisted some "userDidMakePurchase" flag in user defaults as an imperfect solution to using the app w/o a network connection.

Now I'd like to implement an IAP where the user can make it over and over. Each time the user is given ten tokens to use an in-app currency. **How can I determine the number of tokens a particular user has when they start the app?**

So far I've considered persisting a token count in user defaults. This has some major downsides like deleting and reinstalling the app wipes out the user's token balance. Also tokens won't carry over to other devices.

Of course I could persist the token counts on my own server or use AWS. However I'd like to avoid this if possible. I'm only familiar with IAP basics so perhaps Apple keeps track of all purchases and I can just figure it out from there.

Comment: "Of course I could persist the token counts on my own server or use AWS. However I'd like to avoid this if possible." Would you elaboarte why you want to avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Switching from "buy once, use forever" to "buy many times, use while it lasts" makes your purchase a *consumable* in Apple's terminology. Since Apple does not store the state of consumable purchases for you, the task of keeping track of consuming the resource is entirely up to your application.

In general, there are four places that you could potentially use to store the remaining count:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Storage     | Offline? | Reinstall? | Encrypted? | Large? |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Documents Folder |    YES   |     NO     |     NO     |   YES  |
| iCloud           |     NO   |     YES    |     NO     |   YES  |
| User Defaults    |    YES   |     NO     |     NO     |   NO   |
| Keychain         |    YES   |     YES    |     YES    |   NO   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since you need to store a tiny amount of data, your ideal candidate is [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9): it works offline, survives reinstalls, and as an added bonus, it is also encrypted.

Although there is no built-in `NS` wrapper around the keychain `CF` APIs, Apple has kindly [published](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) a nice wrapper for it (scroll to the bottom of the page to see the code). Add security framework to your solution, copy-paste the wrapper code into your project (it's only two files). Now you can use keychain as if it were an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Great thanks for the info! The keychain sounds promising in some ways. However I'm not sure if it solves the multiple device issue. Keychain data isn't synched across devices is it?

Comment: @SundayMonday Unfortunately, sharing consumables across devices is an extremely tricky task, requiring (among other things) a support of transactional updates. Apple indirectly acknowledges the trickiness of getting it right in their In-App Purchase Guidelines by exempting consumables from the sharing requirement: "Consumable items are the one exception to the requirement that your content be available on all the user’s devices. Consumable items are digital items that are used up or disappear after use and can never be reused."

Comment: @SundayMonday If you must implement the sharing, most likely you would need to use a [server product model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html), which is a lot more complex.

Comment: +1 That's interesting. I wonder if the problem can be substantially simplified by airing on the side of caution. Namely if a user purchases 100 coins on their phone then make those 100 coins available on their iPad too unless you can reliably show that the user spent 80 coins on the iPhone. In which case the user has only 20 coins available on the iPad. So a "tie goes to the user" approach seems to make things possible.

Comment: @SundayMonday The "tie goes to the user" approach opens you up to users purposely gaming your app. This may be a problem if the consumable has some value in the real world (say, lets you make phone calls to "real" phones). Consumables are device-by-device items, so their purchase needs to be made with the understanding that they are tied to the specific device. Apple does not let you restore a purchased consumable. You should warn your users that consumables are not shareable, and make it easy for users to purchase smaller blocks of items (e.g. if you offer 100 coins, also offer 50 and 20).

Comment: Can the user open the Keychain to edit your stored values, thereby giving themselves unpaid credits?

Comment: @BasilBourque Can you think of a way for them to do it? Because I can't.

Comment: @BasilBourque They can change it in keychain, if you save your data in String. And strings were seen as passwords, which can be changed by the owner. But if you save  your data in encrypted data, I think maybe they can't changed it directly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably sure that the iCloud key-value store persists across app delete/reinstall.  That might be the way to go.

Otherwise yes you will need your own server to store the token count, along with some way to authenticate the user (device id is no good, what if they replace the device and restore from backup?) and all the attendant hassle - registration, forgot password screens, etc.