# How do I maintain state of in app purchase across devices and restores

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in app purchase for an iOS application
Did some googling and read this thread : [Maintaining records of iOS in-app-purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129571/maintaining-records-of-ios-in-app-purchases)

It seems the way to go indicated is to use keychain

My in app purchase type is - Non-Consumables

Am wondering what is the best strategy for :

## 1

If a user has made an in-app purchase and resets the phone / deletes the app and then again downloads the app - do not want the user to pay up again

## 2

if the user does an in app purchase on an iPhone and then does an update on the iPad - he should get the in app purchase content without paying again

As far as possible do not want to store anything on my server if at all possible and am sure storing something locally on the device is useless for resets / multiple devices

Thanks!
akila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple keeps a record of what the user has purchased.

You also must implement a in app purchase restore button for the user in case of the two situations you mentioned above.

The inapp purchase restore button asks the App Store if the user has purchased before and sends you authorization if the have.

I recommend you use a library like RMStore on github to deal with in app purchases, the only big manual thing you need to do is obfuscate the in app purchase status as it stores it in the NSDefaults.

Comment: thanks - I have started implementing using Storekit - sorry if this is too basic - but any specific reason why I should go with RMStore - any advantages it provides over SK ? thank you

Comment: RMStore uses Store kit, it just makes things a lot less messy. The listener calls from the app store iirc falls under two methods with multiple state possibilities, RMStore just gives you if you have succeeded or not. It also makes it dead easy to retrieve if a person has purchased a product or not by just asking using the product ID. And if you're so keen you can implement some piracy checking by linking it to a web server to check app store receipts.

Comment: Thanks for recommending my library @DavidWong. I'd like to add that I recently added support to persist transactions in the keychain, which requires no obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has made an in-app purchase and resets the phone / deletes the app and then again downloads the app.... you want to restore the transactions by keeping an Restore button . Once you click on the restore button you want to connect with the storekit for restore the transactions. Their you can get the list of products that user has already purchased . Check the list of productids if your productid is match then unlock the content. All the best

Comment: Thanks Krishna - conceptually that is the logic to go with ! :)

Comment: Am I right, that Apple notices a bought product also, if you are going to buy it (This product has allready been bought and will be restored for free)?